# Symfony2 callback validation

Tags: validation, callback, symfony

I'm trying to do something like this
https://github.com/brikou/AcmePizzaBundle/blob/master/Entity/Factory/...
in symfony2 beta1, but it simply does not trigger my validation
callback.

When I try this http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#getters

```
/**
     * @assert:True(message = "The token is invalid")
     */
    public function isTokenValid()
    {
        // return true or false
    }
```

it works, but i want callback validation with ExecutionContext. I hope
that I can access DI container from here and retreive my services.

Any idea why @assert:callback(methods={"isValidFoo"}) is not working?

Comment: Please post your code. Make sure you are spelling the function name correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, those validation callback functions should not return true or false but add violations to an execution context. Check [the documentation.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)